# Nginx not redirecting traffic from http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I have nginx installed on an EC2 server on Amazon Linux 2 and serving my website on HTTP and HTTPS. However, I cannot get the location blocks to be working on HTTP. They work perfectly on HTTPS if I need to serve a file or redirect to a proxy_path, but do not work for HTTP.

I want to redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS.

In addition, even if I remove the first server block, the website is still served through port 80.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

Here is my full nginx configuration file located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name *.example.com;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/test {
                return 200 'test.test';
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a default configuration file that nginx is using?

Answer (score 0):

Your `http` block should look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the nginx.conf file and I am still being sent to HTTP. I am not redirected to HTTPS. It looks like if there was a default HTTP configuration file somewhere that NGINX uses as default.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The main problem was another process caching the requests and running on the host and listening on ports 80 and 443. Killed the process and everything works fine.